# How to move the data spread in multiple rows to a single row using Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with around 20,000 row. The data for each record is put in 4 consecutive rows with a standard pattern. I want to gather the data and present in 1 single row, i.e. open several blank columns and move each data not in the 1st row of that record to the 1st row. Then, remove all blank row in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th row of that record.

**Source file:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Please edit your question and include your code attempt.

Comment: I'd probably use `FIND` to find each instance of _Invoice No_ in column B.  That and the three rows below each find will give me the range of each record.  I'd then pass the info in each of these ranges into a collection, or simple class before arranging it and dumping it back on the sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the values into an array. Scan the array copying relevant elements to an output array and then write the output array to a sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub process()

    Const ROW_START = 4

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, r As Long, rOut As Long
    Dim arIn, arOut, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
  
    ' input
    LastRow = wsIn.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arIn = wsIn.Range("A" & ROW_START & ":J" & LastRow).Value2
    rOut = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(UBound(arIn) / 4, 1)
    ReDim arOut(1 To rOut, 1 To 15)  ' A to O

    ' process
    rOut = 0
    For r = 1 To UBound(arIn)
        If Len(arIn(r, 4)) > 0 Then ' Description
            rOut = rOut + 1
            arOut(rOut, 1) = arIn(r, 1) ' DeparIntment
            arOut(rOut, 2) = arIn(r, 2) ' Invoice No.
            arOut(rOut, 3) = arIn(r + 1, 2) ' PO No.
            arOut(rOut, 4) = arIn(r, 3) ' Date
            arOut(rOut, 5) = arIn(r, 4) ' Description
            arOut(rOut, 6) = arIn(r, 5) ' Category
            arOut(rOut, 7) = arIn(r + 1, 5) ' Quantity
            arOut(rOut, 8) = arIn(r, 6) ' Estimate Amount
            arOut(rOut, 9) = arIn(r + 1, 6) ' No. of Product Requested
            arOut(rOut, 10) = arIn(r + 3, 8) ' Surname
            arOut(rOut, 11) = arIn(r, 8) ' Total Amount
            arOut(rOut, 12) = arIn(r + 1, 8) ' No.of Product Received
            arOut(rOut, 13) = arIn(r + 2, 7) ' Given Name
            arOut(rOut, 14) = arIn(r, 9) ' 1. Yes/No
            arOut(rOut, 15) = arIn(r, 10) ' 2. Yes/No
        End If
    Next

    ' output
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    wsOut.Cells.Clear
    With wsOut.Range("A1:O1")
        .Range("A1:O1").Value2 = Array("Department", "Invoice No.", "PO No.", _
           "Date", "Description", "Category", "Quantity", _
           "Estimate Amount", "No. of Product Requested", _
           "Surname", "Total Amount", "No.of Product Received", _
           "Given Name", "Yes/No", "Yes/No")
         .Columns("A:O").AutoFit
    End With
    wsOut.Range("A2").Resize(rOut, 15).Value2 = arOut
    MsgBox rOut & " rows created on " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.00 secs")

End Sub
```